# error: Object literal may only specify known properties in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm going crazy for this error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'brand' does not exist in type 'BrandCB[]'.
```

I don't know what's happen. How to solve this issue?
this is the code:
**gallery.component.ts**

```
import { CarsService } from '../services/cars.service';
import { Car } from './../models/car';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrandCB } from '../models/brandCB';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

  cars:Car[];
  brands:BrandCB[];
  selectedBrand:string;
  observableCars;
  observableBrands;

  constructor(public carsService: CarsService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCars('all');
    this.observableBrands = this.carsService.getBrands().subscribe( (data:any) => {
      this.brands = {brand:data['brand'], checked:'false'}; //this is the error row
      console.table(data);
    });
  }

  onOptionsSelected(event: { target: { filter: any; }; }){
    this.getCars(this.selectedBrand)
  }

  getCars(filter){

    this.observableCars = this.carsService.getCars().subscribe(data => {

      if(filter!="all"){
        this.cars = data.filter( car => car.brand == this.selectedBrand);
      }else{
        this.cars = data;
      }

    });
  }

  a(event){
    let name = event.target.name;
    let checked = event.target.checked;

    if(name=='all'){
      if(checked==true){
        //uncheck tutti gli altri
      }
    } else {
      // filtra in base alle caselle checked
        // crea un array di checked items
    }

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.observableCars.unsubscribe();
    this.observableBrands.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**brandCB.ts**

```
export class BrandCB {
    brand:any;
    checked:boolean;
}
```

StackOverflow is telling me that my post is mostly code and i should write something else, so I m doing, bla bla bla and more bla bla bla. Have you seen the accident outside?

Comment: What line is the error occurring on. Is this really the smallest code you can create to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: I signed it by comments, look in ngOnInit

Comment: You're assigning an object to an array.

Comment: You have defined brands as an array. Try `this.brands[0] = {brand:data['brand'], checked:'false'};` if you want the first value in the array to equal that object. Or more likely loop over your data and push the objects into the array as needed.

Comment: @ritaj i think this is not the problem, brands[] is an array of objects

Comment: @Sam why in getCars() works fine? I've done the same logic.

Comment: Yeah, and `{brand:data['brand'], checked:'false'}` is NOT an array of objects. Try this: `this.brands = [{brand:data['brand'], checked:'false'}];`

Comment: The reason cars worked is because your data returned from the subscription is an array. And you didn't modify this data apart from filtering it, so you are assigning an array to an array.

Comment: @ritaj your solution doesen't work, it set just one item to array and brand is undefined.

Comment: Of course the brand is undefined, array doesn't have `brand` property. The object inside does. `this.brands[0].brand`

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

```
this.observableBrands = this.carsService.getBrands().subscribe( (data:any) => {
  for(let x=0;x<data.length;x++){
    this.brands.push(new BrandCB(data[x].brand, false));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As your line of error shows, you are trying to assign an object to array. Basically you need to push your brandData in brands array instead of assigning it.

Try this line

```
this.brands = [{brand:data['brand'], checked:'false'}];
```

This will set your brand data to first element of array. But as your service method name is 'getBrands' are you sure only a single brand value will be returned from service instead of array ?